# How to Select File from S3 by wildcard matching

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How to identify/select specific file from S3 based on wildcard matching the filename ?

I want to select the file present on S3 based on **wildcard** pattern matching of the filename, given by the pattern: `DWH_CUST_P665_*.xml` and return the **full** filename of the matched file.
E.g -

- The file "DWH_CUST_P665_20220515_170922.xml" should be **selected** based
  on the wildcard above
- But the file "DWH_PROD_P223_20220607_102314.xml" should be **ignored**.

I need to return the name of the file that matches the wildcard pattern specified above. I have come up with the following code snippet. However, I am struggling to make it work. Can anyone please help to do the pattern matching correctly.

```
import boto3
import os
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class S3Pull:
    def __init__(self, bucket):
        self.bucket = bucket
        self.client = boto3.client('s3')

    def iterate_bucket(self, wildcard=".*"):
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=self.bucket)

        regex = re.compile(wildcard)
        for page in page_iterator:
            if page['KeyCount'] > 0:
                for item in page['Contents']:
                    if re.match(regex, item["Key"])
                       print(item['Key'])
    
    return str(item['Key'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TYPE = "CUST"
    ID = "P665"
    bucket = "dwh-landing-bucket"
    s3_pull = S3Pull(bucket)
    s3_object = s3_pull.iterate_bucket(f"DWH_{TYPE}_{ID}_*.xml")

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=s3_object)

    tree = ET.parse(obj['Body'])
```

I can't seem to get the wildcard pattern match to work correctly and return the matching filename.

Any help is appreciated.

Happy to provide more info.

Comment: From a cursory glance, the regex you use `f"DWH_{TYPE}_{ID}_*.xml"` should probably be `rf"DWH_{TYPE}_{ID}_.*\.xml"` - note the `.` before the `*` and the escaped `\.xml`.